# List sorted Posts on Group and children Groups efficiently

Tags: index, mariadb, materialized-view, mariadb-10.5, sphinx

Say I have a system that has Groups and Posts on those Groups.

A Group can have multiple "child Groups"

> Group 1 > Group 2 > Group 3
> Group 1 > Group 2 > Group 4
> Group 1 > Group 5 > Group 6
> ...

So I have these two tables:

`Groups (*GroupId*, Name, ParentGroupId, ...)`
`Posts (*PostId*, GroupId, UserId, Text, ...)`

Displaying a list of latest 10 posts on Group 3, 4 and 6 isn't a problem.
An index on `GroupId` does it (`WHERE GroupId=12345 ORDER BY PostId DESC`).

However, the challenge I'm having is how can I make Group 2 list posts created directly in Group 2, but also on children (Group 3 and 4), and the same for Group 1 (list posts on Group  1 and on all children, sorted).

The only thing I can think of is to create an extra "indexing table" which will have a list of `PostId` for each Parent Group, and use that to retrieve the Posts. But, I'm afraid that will be a pain to maintain and ensure it's accurate (like using a `TRIGGER`). What if a bug happens and then we have to fix the index, rebuild the whole index again, etc...

Is there a better way of doing this?
I was hoping to use something more native and auto-maintained.

I use MariaDB 10.4 and Sphinx Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to solve is a type of **tree** or **hierarchy** problem. Usually these are solvable with recursion. Specifically in a RDBMS like MariaDB you can use something called a [**Recursive CTE**](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to generate the relational dataset that represents the parent (ancestor) / child tree-like structure of your data.

Just like with recursion in a procedural language, in a recursive CTE, there is a base case aka the **anchor** and the **recursive case** that the anchor is unioned with.

Generic syntax example:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ExampleRecursiveCTE AS 
(
    -- Setting up the anchor / base case
    SELECT
        "" As ParentDescription,
        0 AS ParentId,
        "This is the base case" AS ChildDescription, 
        0 AS ChildId

    UNION ALL

    -- The recursive levels
    SELECT 
         ChildDescription AS ParentDescription, 
         ChildId AS ParentId, -- The ancestor level becomes the parent of this level
         "Some cool stuff about this child" AS ChildDescription,
         ChildId + 1 AS ChildId -- This is the new child level
    FROM ExampleRecursiveCTE
)

SELECT ParentDescription, ParentId, ChildDescription, ChildId
FROM ExampleRecursiveCTE
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, how is it recursive, if you're not referencing ExampleRecursiveCTE inside itself? This just looks like a normal UNION that could be done without CTE.

Comment: @Nuno Apologies, that was a typo. The CTE should reference itself, and I've updated my example to fix that. Thanks!